# Orbeon integration with Alfresco doesn't work when trying to send a PDF version of my form

Tags: debugging, pdf, alfresco, orbeon

**Summary of problem:**
Orbeon Forms 3.9.0 PE Form Runner integration with Alfresco is broken for my form if oxf.fr.alfresco.send-pdf.*.* is set to true in WEB-INF/resources/config/properties-local.xml. The Alfresco integration works correctly for a simple test form, or if Orbeon is configured to send only the XML and not the PDF version. My form that fails was originally created with the CE version of Form Builder and imported into the PE version via cutting and pasting the form source.

**Details of problem:**
I had configured Orbeon to store my form data as both XML and PDF in Alfresco, however nothing was being stored in Alfresco when the send button was pressed - the form contents were only being updated in the Orbeon Forms eXist database.

I then created a simple test form with a single field, and it was successfully sent to Alfresco and both the XML and PDF versions were stored in the configured directory.

Examining the orbeon.log file after sending the both the simple test form and the more complex form which fails shows that the failing form throws a warning in the Orbeon log file which does not occur with the form that succeeds:

```
WARN  XFormsServer  - instance() - instance not found {instance id: "fr-persistence-instance"}
```

I suspect that this is what is causing the failure, but I don't know how to correct it.

Both the orbeon log file and a Wireshark analysis indicate that processing for the failing form stops after the first two steps and never reaches the PDF generation stage.

Here is the traffic generated when trying to send the failing form:

```
No. Stream Time      Protocol Info
  8 1      0.013116  HTTP/XML PUT /orbeon/fr/service/exist/crud/test/alfresco2/data/8758825eb4cb1047b6c70cb9a8021d63/data.xml HTTP/1.1 
 17 3      0.505195  HTTP/XML PUT /orbeon/exist/rest/db/orbeon/fr/test/alfresco2/data/8758825eb4cb1047b6c70cb9a8021d63/data.xml HTTP/1.1 
 19 3      2.703298  HTTP     HTTP/1.1 201 Created 
 23 1      2.728196  HTTP/XML HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

And here is the traffic generated when the simple test form was sent:

```
No. Stream Time      Protocol Info
  8 1      0.008351  HTTP/XML PUT /orbeon/fr/service/exist/crud/test/alfresco/data/4b9597478172d9e3a99db4f333136101/data.xml HTTP/1.1 
 17 3      0.493899  HTTP/XML PUT /orbeon/exist/rest/db/orbeon/fr/test/alfresco/data/4b9597478172d9e3a99db4f333136101/data.xml HTTP/1.1 
 19 3      1.061385  HTTP     HTTP/1.1 201 Created 
 23 1      1.067774  HTTP/XML HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
 27 1      1.266107  HTTP/XML POST /orbeon/fr/service/test/alfresco/pdf/4b9597478172d9e3a99db4f333136101?fr-language=en HTTP/1.1 
 29 3      1.678506  HTTP     GET /orbeon/fr/service/exist/crud/test/alfresco/form/form.xhtml?document=4b9597478172d9e3a99db4f333136101 HTTP/1.1 
 34 4      1.724603  HTTP     GET /orbeon/exist/rest/db/orbeon/fr/test/alfresco/form/form.xhtml HTTP/1.1 
 63 4      1.887303  HTTP/XML HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
 66 3      1.887533  HTTP/XML HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
 69 3      3.401139  HTTP     GET /orbeon/fr/service/exist/crud/test/alfresco/data/4b9597478172d9e3a99db4f333136101/data.xml HTTP/1.1 
 71 4      3.466335  HTTP     GET /orbeon/exist/rest/db/orbeon/fr/test/alfresco/data/4b9597478172d9e3a99db4f333136101/data.xml HTTP/1.1 
 74 4      3.467743  HTTP/XML HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
 78 3      3.469550  HTTP/XML HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
 83 5      7.379995  HTTP     GET /orbeon/xforms-server/3.9.0.201105152053/orbeon-f8ea744bfde8e279e895681476e87b4ae5eec96a.css HTTP/1.1 
 94 5      7.601110  HTTP     HTTP/1.1 200 OK  (text/css)
 96 5      7.636405  HTTP     GET /orbeon/xforms-server/3.9.0.201105152053/orbeon-c2aa09348528b375f1cb95d729030dfb1a6373a0.css HTTP/1.1 
107 5      7.698251  HTTP     HTTP/1.1 200 OK  (text/css)
109 1      8.540060  HTTP/XML HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
111 1      8.565153  HTTP     GET /orbeon/xforms-server/dynamic/90101f83d4c2f6ea307ee44255f29a21 HTTP/1.1 
114 1      8.598588  HTTP     HTTP/1.1 200 OK  (application/pdf)
118 1      8.648522  HTTP/XML POST /alfresco/api/AuthenticationService HTTP/1.1 
121 1      8.818012  HTTP/XML HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
125 1      8.848028  HTTP/XML POST /alfresco/api/RepositoryService HTTP/1.1 
128 1      11.108350 HTTP/XML HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
132 1      11.123460 HTTP/XML POST /alfresco/api/ContentService HTTP/1.1 
135 1      11.238135 HTTP/XML HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
139 1      11.272450 HTTP/XML POST /alfresco/api/AuthenticationService HTTP/1.1 
142 1      11.287273 HTTP/XML HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
145 1      11.300528 HTTP/XML POST /alfresco/api/RepositoryService HTTP/1.1 
148 1      11.524832 HTTP/XML HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
151 1      11.533724 HTTP/XML POST /alfresco/api/ContentService HTTP/1.1 
154 1      11.610843 HTTP/XML HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
156 1      12.522981 HTTP     GET /orbeon/fr/service/exist/crud/test/alfresco/form/form.xhtml?document=My-Confirmation-Page HTTP/1.1 
157 3      12.556468 HTTP     GET /orbeon/exist/rest/db/orbeon/fr/test/alfresco/form/form.xhtml HTTP/1.1 
183 3      12.688109 HTTP/XML HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
186 1      12.688383 HTTP/XML HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
194 7      13.630066 HTTP     GET /web-assets/FormSiteLogo.png HTTP/1.1 
198 7      13.631951 HTTP     HTTP/1.1 200 OK  (PNG)
```

Noting that it was prior to the PDF generation that the process had failed, I turned off sending the PDF version to Alfresco and then the XML version of the original form was successfully saved to Alfresco. Here's the traffic from sending the form:

```
No. Stream Time      Protocol Info
  8 1      0.007190  HTTP/XML PUT /orbeon/fr/service/exist/crud/test/alfresco2/data/8758825eb4cb1047b6c70cb9a8021d63/data.xml HTTP/1.1 
 17 3      0.447543  HTTP/XML PUT /orbeon/exist/rest/db/orbeon/fr/test/alfresco2/data/8758825eb4cb1047b6c70cb9a8021d63/data.xml HTTP/1.1 
 19 3      1.048508  HTTP     HTTP/1.1 201 Created 
 23 1      1.075924  HTTP/XML HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
 27 1      1.365397  HTTP/XML POST /alfresco/api/AuthenticationService HTTP/1.1 
 31 1      1.775457  HTTP/XML HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
 35 1      1.815342  HTTP/XML POST /alfresco/api/RepositoryService HTTP/1.1 
 38 1      3.784269  HTTP/XML HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
 42 1      3.794841  HTTP/XML POST /alfresco/api/ContentService HTTP/1.1 
 45 1      4.441574  HTTP/XML HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

With the PDF sending still turned off, I examined the behaviour of sending the simple test form and noticed that it still generates some additional traffic that my original form doesn't produce (packets 53 thru 97 below):

```
No. Stream Time      Protocol Info
 12 2      0.296627  HTTP/XML PUT /orbeon/fr/service/exist/crud/test/alfresco/data/4b9597478172d9e3a99db4f333136101/data.xml HTTP/1.1 
 21 3      0.543543  HTTP/XML PUT /orbeon/exist/rest/db/orbeon/fr/test/alfresco/data/4b9597478172d9e3a99db4f333136101/data.xml HTTP/1.1 
 23 3      0.734490  HTTP     HTTP/1.1 201 Created 
 27 2      0.743573  HTTP/XML HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
 31 2      0.822314  HTTP/XML POST /alfresco/api/AuthenticationService HTTP/1.1 
 37 2      0.988298  HTTP/XML HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
 41 2      0.997752  HTTP/XML POST /alfresco/api/RepositoryService HTTP/1.1 
 44 2      1.117861  HTTP/XML HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
 48 2      1.128387  HTTP/XML POST /alfresco/api/ContentService HTTP/1.1 
 51 2      1.340271  HTTP/XML HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
 53 2      1.932827  HTTP     GET /orbeon/fr/service/exist/crud/test/alfresco/form/form.xhtml?document=My-Confirmation-Page HTTP/1.1 
 55 3      1.953312  HTTP     GET /orbeon/exist/rest/db/orbeon/fr/test/alfresco/form/form.xhtml HTTP/1.1 
 83 3      1.984616  HTTP/XML HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
 86 2      1.984743  HTTP/XML HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
 94 5      3.356853  HTTP     GET /web-assets/FormSiteLogo.png HTTP/1.1 
 97 5      3.358165  HTTP     HTTP/1.1 200 OK  (PNG)
```

The form that fails to be sent when PDF sending is turned on was originally created with the CE version of Orbeon Forms. That may or may not be significant to the problem, but I'm guessing that's why there's some extra stuff going on with the simple test form that isn't happening with the form that originated in the CE version.

Comment: I forgot to mention that PDF generation outside of the send workflow process does work correctly, as pressing the PDF button does generate a PDF that is downloaded to the browser.

Comment: I've determined that the bug is caused by a control that is 1) non-visible, 2) required, and 3) empty. If it's not visible, it shouldn't matter if it is empty. The "Save" and "PDF" buttons treat the field that way and behave as expected. But the "Send" button exhibits broken behavior if the field is empty even though it isn't visible.

Comment: This issue has now been resolved. For more info see: http://orbeon-forms-ops-users.24843.n4.nabble.com/Bug-in-Orbeon-s-Alfesco-Integration-when-sending-PDF-of-form-with-non-visible-control-td3900025.html

Answer (score 0):

This issue has now been resolved. Here is the solution:

> persistence-model.xml does not have the validate="false" attribute set. Apparently that is a change that was made since 3.9 20110515 stable was released. I added the validate="false" attribute to fr-pdf-service-submission in apps/fr/includes/persistence-model.xml in the orbeon-form-runner.jar file in the 3.9 stable release and it now sends the PDF to Alfresco successfully.

**References**

- [Orbeon Alfresco Integration when sending PDF with non-visible control](http://orbeon-forms-ops-users.24843.n4.nabble.com/Bug-in-Orbeon-s-Alfesco-Integration-when-sending-PDF-of-form-with-non-visible-control-td3900025.html)
- [Orbeon Github Issue: Non-relevant but invalid section content prevents workflow-send from working](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/commit/4ed1009d1af9622c06202377a79cfe670d9aafb0)